# React Native + TypeScript, can't set State

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, typescript2.0

I know my functioning is running but for whatever reason I can't set the state of this property "isLoggedIn"

In the componentDidMount() I setState based on login detection and it doesn't seem to work.

```
import React, {
   Component
} from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, View, StyleSheet, Text } from 'react-native';
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';

import Firestack from 'react-native-firestack';

const firestack = new Firestack();

interface Props {
   isLoggedIn?: boolean;
}

interface State {
   isLoggedIn: boolean;
}


export default class MainList extends Component<Props, State> {

    state = {
      isLoggedIn: false,
    };

    constructor(props: any) {

       super(props);
       console.log("Is anyone logged in?: " + this.isLoggedIn);

    }

    isLoggedIn = this.state.isLoggedIn;

    componentDidMount() {

      firestack.auth.listenForAuth((evt: any) => {
      // evt is the authentication event
      // it contains an `error` key for carrying the
      // error message in case of an error
      // and a `user` key upon successful authentication

        if (!evt.authenticated) {
        // There was an error or there is no user
        //console.error(evt.error);

        this.setState({isLoggedIn: false});
        console.log("The state of isLoggedIn is: " + this.isLoggedIn);

        } else {
        // evt.user contains the user details
        console.log('User details', evt.user);

        this.setState({isLoggedIn: true});
        console.log("The state of isLoggedIn is: " + this.isLoggedIn);

        }

        if (!this.isLoggedIn) {

            Actions.welcome();

        }


    }); 

}

render() {

    return (
        <View style={styles.View}>

            <Text style={styles.textLabel}>The main view</Text>

        </View>
       )

     }

  }

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

    View: {
       padding: 20
    },
   textLabel: {
    fontSize: 20,
    marginBottom: 10,
    height: 20
  },
textInput: {
    height: 20,
    fontSize: 15,
    marginBottom: 20
}

 });

 AppRegistry.registerComponent('MainList', ()=> MainList);
```

Anything that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: you can not set state inside componentDidMount()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    this.setState({isLoggedIn: false});
    console.log("The state of isLoggedIn is: " + this.isLoggedIn);
```

This code will not work. `setState` is asynchronous, so `this.isLoggedIn` is not necessarily updated immediately after you call `setState`. If you want to access the new value immediately, use the callback that triggers when the state is set:

```
this.setState({ isLoggedIn: false }, () => console.log(this.state.isLoggedIn));
```

Or, use this method of setting the state:

```
this.setState(oldState => {
    oldState.isLoggedIn = false;

    console.log(oldState.isLoggedIn);
    return oldState;
});
```

Comment: thank you i didn't think to think that it was asynchronous...good to know there.  fixed my problem now :-)  thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Fetch data in componentDidMount. When the response arrives, store the data in state by calling setstate inside callback.

componentDidMount() is invoked immediately after a component is mounted. Initialization that requires DOM nodes should go here. If you need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to instantiate the network request. Setting state in this method will trigger a re-rendering.